# Issue in running multiple batch files sequentially from a master file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to execute two batch files in parallel and the third batch file once the above two batch files have completed their execution.

I created a master file with the following code

> Call EG1.bat 
>   Call EG2.bat 
>   PAUSE

EG1.bat is

> cd Directory 
>   START cscript "X.vbs" 
>   START csript "Y.vbs"

EG2.bat is

> cd Directory 
>   START cscript "Z.vbs"

Now ideally since CALL is being used to trigger the scripts, EG2.bat should be executed after the EG1.bat is completed executing. However, post completion also EG2.bat doesnt get triggered.

How do i return the control back to master batch file once the EG1 is done (EXIT doesnt help) and start executing EG2.bat

I looked similar posts as well but that doesn't help.(Most of them ask to use the call function)

I also tried using START /wait instead of CALL and found it to be of no help either.

Comment: What exactly happens?  Is there an error message?  Since the first batch file changes the directory, it is possible that the second batch file isn't being found; one way to fix this would be to use `cmd /c` instead of `call`.

Comment: All the batch files including the master batch file are in the same location. Also, there is no error message message but the command prompt for the EX1.bat is just as is and control doesn't move to the mastel bat again

Comment: What do you mean by "the command prompt for the EX1.bat" ?  Can you post or email me a screenshot?

Comment: I see you've posted another question.  Have you solved this problem?